# light-weight timer in C

Tags: c, timer

I'm looking for a light weight timer to measure timing of few sections of a C code. This timer implementation shouldn't add to the overall program execution time.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a Q&A, not a "find a library for me" site.

Comment: BTW, "code" in this context is an uncountable noun, so "a code" is incorrect.

Comment: What resolution do you need? Seconds? Milliseconds? Microseconds? And what operating system? The localtime() family of functions in the Unix standard C library could work...

Comment: "This timer implementation shouldn't add to the overall program execution time." Good luck with that. Let me know when you find one.

Comment: that was a question indeed..I was looking for differ timer implementations and looking for a light weight one. Even I know that this is not a "find a library for me" site.. "A code" meant a C program..

Comment: nmichaels: I meant it shouldn't add a large overhead in the original program execution time.

Comment: There is way too much information missing from your question. What OS and hardware platform are you asking about? When it comes to timers things are quite diverse. What kind of resolution do you need? Do you need wall-clock time (e.g. for multimedia applications) or CPU-clock time?

Comment: Timers aren't part of any C standard, so C is completely irrelevent to this question. I suggest you take it out of the tags, and instead tell us what OS, and perhaps what hardware you are using.

Comment: @mcmk: Sorry, the snark is hard to suppress. This is a reasonable question to ask on SO and a quick search doesn't turn up any decent results. You'll probably get a better answer if you edit your question to include your target platform and the level of precision you need. Depending on why you want it, adding that may also help.

Comment: @Jonas Gulle - That would be my answer too...assuming he's running on an x86-compatable. These days, with all the Android and IOS and Mac developers running around here, that isn't such a good assumption.

Answer (score 3):

Look at [`clock_gettime`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html) for POSIX-compliant platforms; you can do it yourself really easily by comparing one timestamp with one generated a little later.

Remember to use the `CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID` or `CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID` parameters to specify that you want CPU time taken just by *that process* (and its children) or thread, and not the wider, absolute, "wall" time.

An [alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/733530/visual-c-how-to-get-the-cpu-time) on Windows might be [`GetProcessTimes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683223%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: `gettimeofday()` is marked obsolescent in POSIX 2008, a better option is `clock_gettime()`

Comment: "obsolescent" is the term in the POSIX reference I use (see the link in my answer). *I think "obsolete" is for functions already removed and "obsolescent" for functions marked for removal*

Comment: @pmg: Ah ok yes, it does appear to be a valid, different word.

Comment: `clock_gettime` can measure cpu time too, not only realtime.

Answer (score 2):

What is time?

Imagine your code took 3 miliseconds ... but it runs on 3 cores ... it used 2 milliseconds on core 1; 1.5 milliseconds on core 2; and 1.2 milliseconds on core 3 for a total of 4.7 milliseconds.

So ... is 3 milliseconds the same as 4.7 milliseconds?

Oh, don't forget that those 4.7 milliseconds were in fact also used to filter incoming internet connections and to download anti-virus database.

**Use a profiler**, and even then, don't trust the results :)

---

For POSIX, try <s>[`gettimeofday()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/gettimeofday.html) *(obsolescent)*</s> [`clock_gettime()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/clock_gettime.html).
For Windows, apparently, you can use [`GetSystemTime()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724390%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing to profiling without observation interference is `oprofile`. But it can't directly measure intervals; it only gives you a statistical map of where the whole program (or whole system) is spending its time.

If you really want cheap interval timing, on x86 you can use the `rdtsc` instruction in inline asm.

```
static inline unsigned rdtsc()
{
    unsigned x;
    __asm__ __volatile__ ( "rdtsc" : "=a"(x) : : "edx" );
    return x;
}
```

Use this to save the timestamp before and after and take the difference. You could modify this code to save the full 64-bit result, but I opted just for the 32-bit result assuming you'll be timing intervals shorter than 4 billion cycles and don't want to waste time on 64-bit subtraction.